# UIButton doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uibutton

I write a uibutton with following code

```
btnSet = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btnSet.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 146, 30);
[btnSet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btnbg.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnSet addTarget:self action:@selector(visitSet) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btnSet setTitle:@"SetIt" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btnSet.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
btnSet.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[self.view addSubview:btnSet];

- (void) visitSet
 {
    NSLog(@"visit set");
    btnSet.selected = YES;
 }
```

the button's background when its status is selected, but the code doesn't work, there's no response after the button is clicked, no log output.

Comment: How is `btnSet` declared, can you post some more context to the first code block? You should be using `[btnSet setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal]` by the way - not setting the `textColor` of the `titleLabel`.

Comment: Just a one off, but did you try changing the method header to this? - (void)visitSet:(UIButton *)sender; and then in your selector (visitSet:) ?

Comment: I have checked with your code it's working. check your rest of the code causing any issue.

Comment: Make sure that the button lies within the frame of the superview and that its superview userInteractionEnabled flag is set to YES.